# Macbook crashes maybe after ram replacement or not

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, crash

I have MacBook 17' early 2011, that max ram is supposed to be 8gb, but I recently installed Crucial 16gb new ram.

I had it crashing several times and not turning on, but finally, it worked out and it gave this report. What is the problem?
I also performed apple Hardware test and it said all is ok.

```
Anonymous UUID:       E6AB578F-B9C1-A318-A38C-85BFD2F7D294

Sat Sep 16 00:06:10 2017

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c09
 family: 6 model: 42 stepping: 7 microcode: 40
 signature: 0x206a7
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2720QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
 9 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003f7f85fc819d
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x000000000003ffff
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003f7f85fc819d
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x000000000003ffff
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003f7f87757b08
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x000000000003ffff
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003f7f87757b08
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x000000000003ffff
Processor 6: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003f7f86fff8a8
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x000000000003ffff
Processor 7: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003f7f86fff8a8
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x000000000003ffff
panic(cpu 7 caller 0xffffff8003dfeef5): "Machine Check at 0x00007fff8f673454, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000011031c000, CR3: 0x00000004564c8077, CR4: 0x00000000000626e0\n" "RAX: 0x000060000006f540, RBX: 0x0000608000095bd0, RCX: 0x00007fff95bb59e8, RDX: 0x0000608000095bd0\n" "RSP: 0x00007fff54a1a4b8, RBP: 0x00007fff54a1a4f0, RSI: 0x00007fff78aaf552, RDI: 0x00006180000cd190\n" "R8:  0x0000000000000016, R9:  0x00007fff7ba57518, R10: 0x00007fff95bb59e8, R11: 0x0000608000104f80\n" "R12: 0x00007fff8f66f000, R13: 0x00007fff98909bb0, R14: 0x00006180000cd190, R15: 0x00007fff78aaf552\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000202, RIP: 0x00007fff8f673454, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.70.16/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 7), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81ebf13dd0 : 0xffffff8003ce953c 
0xffffff81ebf13e50 : 0xffffff8003dfeef5 
0xffffff81ebf13fb0 : 0xffffff8003c9ae2f 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Finder

Mac OS version:
16G29

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: D3314D98-5D40-3CD8-98A4-F1DD46C20E03
Kernel slide:     0x0000000003a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8003b00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,3 (Mac-942459F5819B171B)
```

Comment: If you put the 8GB back, does the issue go away?

Comment: Did you try resetting SMC?

Comment: Hey Amit, yes Ive tried, I just dont understand what is the reason, maybe it can be seen in the code of the report, but this site wont allow me to paste it all. :(

Comment: @Allan Hey Allan, I didnt really do anything but it seems to be working ok now, Im wondering if there is a special patch for Macbook to not react negatively to not original new ram..

Comment: There's no "patch" for memory.  It's either recognized or not.  I would run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to verify everything.  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.